# django valueslist queryset across database engines

Tags: django

In one of the django apps we use two database engine A and B, both are the same database but with different schemas. We have a table called C in both schemas but using db routing it's always made to point to database B. We have formed a valuelist queryset from one of the models in A, tried to pass the same in table C using filter condition `__in` but it always fetches empty though there are matching records. When we convert valueslist queryset to a list and use it in table C using filter condition `__in` it works fine.

Not working

```
data = modelindbA.objects.values_list('somecolumn',flat=True)
info = C.objects.filter(somecolumn__in=data).values_list
```

Working

```
data = modelindbA.objects.values_list('somecolumn',flat=True)
data = list(data)
info = C.objects.filter(somecolumn__in=data).values_list
```

I have read django docs and other SO questions, couldn't find anything relative. My guess is that since both models are in different database schemas the above is not working.  I need assistance on how to troubleshoot this issue.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a queryset with `__in`, Django will construct a single SQL query that uses a subquery for the `__in` clause. Since the two tables are in different databases, no rows will match.

By contrast, if you convert the first queryset to a list, Django will go ahead and fetch the data from the first database. When you then pass that data to the second query, hitting the second database, it will work as expected.

See the [documentation for the `in` field lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in) for more details:

> You can also use a queryset to dynamically evaluate the list of values instead of providing a list of literal values.... This queryset will be evaluated as subselect statement:
>
> ```
> SELECT ... WHERE blog.id IN (SELECT id FROM ... WHERE NAME LIKE '%Cheddar%')
> ```

Comment: Thank you Kevin. Also I tried this way too but it didn;t work out which puzzles me more :(   
data = list(modelindbA.objects.values_list('somecolumn',flat=True)) 
info = C.objects.filter(somecolumn__in=data).values_list
I was expecting this to work because on using list db hit would have been forced and there values would have been into data object already. But even this doesn't work out. Can you please throw some insight on this strange behaviour, thanks a lot for your info on this.

Comment: @Giri: I'm confused, in your question you said that method was "Working".

Comment: Kevin I mean converting valueslist queryset to a list and querying the model in another database works fine. My doubt is : <br> data = list(modelindbA.objects.values_list('somecolumn',flat=True)).  By using "list" above there will be an immediate database hit and values will be fetched from model and will be in variable "data". Now if I use this "data" variable over <br> info = C.objects.filter(somecolumn__in=data).values_list, I was expecting this to work as object is already present in "data" variable by now.

Answer (score 0):

Because *values_list* method returns *django.db.models.query.QuerySet*, not a list.
When you use it with same schema the orm optimise it and should make just one query, but when schemas are different it fails.
Just use list().

I would even recommend to use it for one schema since it can decrease complexity of query and work better on big tables.